# Multithreading crawler get slower and slower after running for some time

Tags: python-3.x, tcp, python-requests, windows-10, python-multithreading

I wrote a multithreaded web crawler under Windows. The libraries that I used were `requests` and `threading`. I found the program became slower and slower after running for some time (about 500 pages). When I stop the program and run again, the program speeds up again. It seems that there are many pending connections, causing the slowdown. How should I manage the problem?

My code:

```
import requests, threading,queue
req = requests.Session()

urlQueue = queue.Queue()
pageList = []
urlList = [url1,url2,....url500]
[urlQueue.put(i) for i in urlList]

def parse(urlQueue):

    try:
       url = urlQueue.get_nowait()
    except:
       break
    try:
       page = req.get(url)
       pageList.append(page)
    except:
       continue

if __name__ == '__main__':

    threadNum = 4
    threadList = []
    for i in threadNum:
        t = threading.Thread(target=(parse),args=(urlQueue,))
        threadList.append(t)
    for thread in threadList:
        thread.start()
    for thread in threadList:
        thread.join()
```

I searched for the problem. An answer told that it was the reuse and recycling problem of TCP under Linux. I don't understand that answer very well. The answer is below. I translated the answer from the Chinese.

1. Type command in Linux shell: `netstat -n | awk '/^tcp/ {++S[$NF]} END {for(a in S) print a, S[a]}'`
2. Found the `TIME_WAIT` is nearly 2W. So, there must be many TCP connections.
3. Use the following code to set the reuse time and recycling time, respectively of TCP:
   `echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_reuse`, `echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_recycle`

That answer seems correct. It should be a network problem. How should I solve this under Windows.

Comment: Hey, @Yuan, could you link to that answer, it may help us. Welcome to SO(StackOverflow), by the way :).

Comment: Hey @Mr.Zeus, I added the answer I found for a similar problem under Linux. Yeah, It must be helpful!!. Thank you for reminding me!

Comment: Thank's, @Yuan! I will take another look at your issue tomorrow. Sorry I can't look at it sooner.

Comment: It's is an interesting question. May be it can help you on Windows. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGLW6_5.2.1/com.ibm.p8.performance.doc/p8ppt014.htm

Comment: @kcorlidy Thank you so much for the reference. I will try this one. If I succeed, I will share the answer!

Comment: Thanks for the contribution to the questions. With your help, I found the answer. Thank you!!!

Comment: Can you increase the ephemeral port range or select a local port to bind to?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I considered whether we can increase TCP connections. I do not have the knowledge in this area, though. Hope somebody could manage this, and edit the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multithreaded crawler will exhaust the TCP connections. We need to set the `TcpTimedWaitDelay` to quickly reuse and recycle the TCP connections. We can solve the problem by manually changing the `regedit` or typing the code.

**How to do it on Windows with code: 
(You need to run the code as an administrator, or otherwise, an error would be raised.**)

```
import win32api,win32con

key = win32api.RegOpenKey(win32con.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters', 0, win32con.KEY_SET_VALUE)

win32api.RegSetValueEx(key, 'TcpTimedWaitDelay', 0, win32con.REG_SZ, '30')

win32api.RegCloseKey(key)
```

**How to do it on Windows manually:**

1. Open `RUN`, and type `regedit`
2. Find: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters`
3. Click `Edit` - `New` - `Expandable String Value`
4. Create `TcpTimedWaitDelay` (if this entry already existed, you do not need to create)
5. Change the value to 30. (The TCP value ranges from 30 to 300 seconds, and the default is 120 seconds. The default value is too
   long for multithreading crawler.)

Thank you for all of your guys' contribute to the questions. This helps a lot of people.

[Reference site](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGLW6_5.2.1/com.ibm.p8.performance.doc/p8ppt014.htm)

Comment: Nice job, @Yuan! Good luck on writing your web crawler.

Comment: You might want to take a look at how you can format your questions to make them more readable and prettier. `:D`

Comment: @Mr.Zeus I see. I will try the best to improve that. Thanks.

Comment: I added another way to solve the problem with the code. I think it is pythonic.

Comment: Perfectly Pythonic. You may(not a must, up to you) add spaces between function arguments to make them(again, in my opinion) more readable. Two options makes it even easier. Too bad I don't have a windows machine to try it with. ;)

Comment: Thanks again. I improved that. It looks better now.